# Read from params[] in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use:

```
<%= select( "payment", "id", { "Visa" => "1", "Mastercard" => "2"}) %>
```

and I get this in HTML

```
<select id="payment_id" name="payment[id]"><option value="2">Mastercard</option>
<option value="1">Visa</option></select>
```

now how can I read the `payment[id]` with `params[]`, if I use params[payment[id]] I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose is better to have

`params[:payment][:id]`

Params is a hash and can be contain some other hash.

Comment: shouldn't this be params[:payment][:id]

Answer (score 3):

This one had me stumbled for a couple of hours when I first started with ruby/rails. In your controller and views you can access the payment's id with either:

```
params[:payment][:id]
```

or...

```
params['payment']['id']
```

Many people prefer using symbols (:symbol) over strings because of memory usage, no matter how small the gains...

Answer (score 0):

params[:payment][:id] and params[:payment][:id] is the same on surface ,
but in fact , in ruby ,you can't access the payment's id with params[:payment][:id].
because rails has changed the usage of it.

Comment: do you have a typo?  Because for the life of me, all three `params[:payment][:id]` look the same here in your answer